# Getting Bitmap of MapView fails if it has never been visible

Tags: android, android-mapview, viewswitcher

I have an app with a ViewSwitcher which holds a MapView and another View and I want to save the MapView's bitmap as an image. This works well, if the MapView has been visible at least once by doing something like that:

```
mapView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap bm = mapView.getDrawingCache();
/* ... save bitmap ... */
```

Problem is, if the MapView hasn't been visible, `getDrawingCache()` returns `null` for the bitmap. Is there any way how I can resolve that?

Comment: [GoogleMap.snapshot()](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18231795/2531709) to the rescue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out how to do it. There are two things to do:

To get the bitmap, create your own one and make the MapView draw into it:

```
    Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(400, 400, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bm);
    mapView.draw(canvas);
```

If you do so, you'll have all your overlays in the bitmap, but not the map image (the tiles). To achieve that too, you'll have to invoke `mapView.preLoad()` prior to drawing the map onto your bitmap.

Comment: This is great, but I can't find a `preLoad()` method on my `MapView`?  Weirdly, it's documented though.  It's a `com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView` if that makes a difference.

Comment: That makes a big difference as what you're using is Android Maps API V2 -- they've changed everything there and it is no longer possible to get an image of the map at all - because they are using a SurfaceView now to render it :-(