# How to take google Maps v2 snapshot?

Tags: android, google-maps

i have to solve this with the new "snapshot maker" which is implemented in the google maps release august but i dont' know how to do this.
Can somone give me a simple example?

here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
static LatLng HAMBURG = new LatLng(47.524749, 21.632745);
GoogleMap map;
File dbFile;
private File imageFile;


@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    PolylineOptions line = new PolylineOptions();

    map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
            .getMap();
    /*
     * Adatbázis
     */
    try {
        dbFile = getDatabasePath("/mnt/sdcard/Download/TeleSensors.db");
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

    SQLiteDatabase myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(
            dbFile.getAbsolutePath(), null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    Cursor curTAB = myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM  GPS_Values;", null);

    Integer count = 0;
    while (curTAB.moveToNext()) {
        String s_latitude = curTAB.getString(1);
        String s_longitude = curTAB.getString(2);
        count++;
        double latitude = Double.parseDouble(s_latitude);
        double longitude = Double.parseDouble(s_longitude);
        line.add(new LatLng(latitude, longitude));

        Log.i("Coordinates",
                s_latitude.toString() + " --- " + s_longitude.toString());

    }
    curTAB.close();
    myDataBase.close();
    // adatbázis vége

    map.addPolyline(line);

    // map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
    // map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE);
    map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    // map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
    // map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);

    // Move the camera instantly to hamburg with a zoom of 15.
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(HAMBURG, 15));

    // Zoom in, animating the camera.
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15), 2000, null);  


}
```

}

Thank you very mouch!

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get snapshot from Google Map V2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16435842/how-to-get-snapshot-from-google-map-v2)

Comment: check  http://stackoverflow.com/a/18308611/2398886 with complete steps and example

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to call the Google maps snapshot method in a button listener because if you should take it too early, it will  give you error `bitmap width has to be larger than 0` or something like this.
Here is the code

```
private void button_listener() {
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SnapshotReadyCallback callback = new SnapshotReadyCallback() {
                    Bitmap bitmap;

                    @Override
                    public void onSnapshotReady(Bitmap snapshot) {
                        bitmap = snapshot;
                        try {
                            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("/mnt/sdcard/Download/TeleSensors.png");
                            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                };

                map.snapshot(callback);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: unable to resolve (snapshot(callback)). am i missing something?

Answer (score 10):

This one is better, it waits for your Map to be fully rendered, before taking the snapshot.

It was updated on 31-Oct-2013.

```
mMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback() {
    public void onMapLoaded() {
        mMap.snapshot(new GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback() {
            public void onSnapshotReady(Bitmap bitmap) {
                // Write image to disk
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("/mnt/sdcard/map.png");
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Extracted from http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.sg/2013/10/ghost-markers-in-your-neighborhood-new.html

Answer (score 5):

Try for **Kotlin** **Android** like this when click on button to take **google map** snapshot:

```
val snapshotReadyCallback : GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback = GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback { selectedScreenShot ->
    ivMapPreview.setImageBitmap(selectedScreenShot);
}

val onMapLoadedCallback : GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback = GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback {
    mMap!!.snapshot(snapshotReadyCallback)
}

mMap!!.setOnMapLoadedCallback(onMapLoadedCallback)
```

Be successful.

Comment: Best Answer. You saved my day

Comment: @vidakamalifar I have do nothing dear Vida. I hope my answer be useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

I' ve tried the accepted answer but it didn't work then tried another approach  that worked for me.

```
private void CaptureScreen() {
        if(initMap()){
            SnapshotReadyCallback callback = new SnapshotReadyCallback() {
                Bitmap bitmap=null;

                @Override
                public void onSnapshotReady(Bitmap snapshot) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    bitmap = snapshot;
                    try {
                        saveImage(bitmap);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                private void saveImage(Bitmap bitmap) throws IOException{
                    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 40, bytes);
                    File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "test.png");
                    f.createNewFile();
                    FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
                    fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                    fo.close();

                }
            };

            mMap.snapshot(callback);
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Map is not Initialized yet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return ;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can also try it without testing for initMap() which is a custom method defined to check if the map is initialized before taking snap. thanks

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#snapshot(com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback, android.graphics.Bitmap)

> **public final void snapshot (GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback callback)**
>
> *Takes a snapshot of the map.* You can use snapshots within your application when an interactive map would be difficult, or impossible,
>   to use. For example, images produced with the snapshot() method can be
>   used to display a thumbnail of the map in your app, or a snapshot in
>   the notification center.

Comment: yes i've read this but i can't do this thats why i asked for an example

Comment: Why don't you tell us in your question? What's the problem?