# How to display a static map like google now

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary, directions

I wanted to display the directions like google now

I just wanted the image that shows directions between two points

I was trying like this but unable to succeed

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=&markers=color:red%7Ccolor:red%7Clabel:C%7C17.1234,78.2345|7Dcolor:red%7Dlabel:C%7D17.968046,78.968046&zoom=10&size=1000x300&sensor=false
```

[image: Help me to get the directions like this]

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve that by taking a snapshot of current Map (here's a thread that shows how to do that: [How to take google Maps v2 snapshot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18231403/how-to-take-google-maps-v2-snapshot)), and then crop the image to desired dimensions.

Comment: I have 2 lat, longs and I need the directions between them in form of an image.